# difference between usage of rostime::Now & toSec for Matlab

Tags: ros, matlab, timestamp, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

i have some troubles and hope that you can help me.
I want to use the time that i got from ROS in Matalb. First i used the command ros::Time::now(); and i got for each frame a timestamp. And now in matlab, i want to use the difference between the timestamp (eg. timestamp[3] - timestamp [2] or timestamp[4] - timestamp [3]) for further calculations. But the problem is that  i always got the value 0 when i calcute the difference.
And now i have used the function toSec in ROS. And when i calculate the difference in matlab, i have results # 0, meanings "better results".
I have read the wiki http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time , but it doesnt tell or explain exactly what is the difference between using or working with the ros::Time or toSec ? I hope please that you can better lighten it

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251873/difference-between-usage-of-rostime::now-&-tosec-for-matlab/) by [Sami](https://answers.ros.org/users/29028/sami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::Time::now()` gives you an actual time stamp as an object. `toSec()` just converts this into a double represenation in seconds. Subtracting time stamps and calling `toSec()` on this should work and give you correct results.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sami](https://answers.ros.org/users/29028/sami/) on 2017-01-13**:
Thanks for the reply. Thanks. That means, for the evaluation of results in matlab, it is better to use the function `toSec()`  and not to use directly the value of `ros::Time::now()`  (meanings the timestamp value) ?

**Comment by [Sami](https://answers.ros.org/users/29028/sami/) on 2017-01-13**:
In Matlab,if want to work with timestamp, its better to tranform it using `toSec`? Is there a difference, if i first,for each time stamp that i receive, use the function `toSec` and then calculate the difference between values that follow each other, then i publish them or if I do it like you said?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2017-01-15**:
besides double inaccuracies that should give you the same result, i.e., a time difference in seconds. If Matlab can't handle the ros::Time class, then you can use the time stamp in seconds.